# SwiftUI: NavigationLink is always activated when in a List

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationlink

I can't prevent `SwiftUI`'s `NavigationLink` from being activated when in a `List`, I have this simple piece of code in which I need to do some kind of business check before deciding to show the details page or not (in a real world app, there might be some business logic happens inside the button's action):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showDetail = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Text 1")
                Text("Text 2")
                Text("Text 3")
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $showDetail) {
                    LinkView(showDetails: $showDetail)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LinkView: View {
    @Binding var showDetails: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showDetails = false
        }) {
            Text("Open Details")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
    }
}
```

how can I prevent navigation link from opening the details page in this case ? and is this a bug in the SDK ?

p.s. XCode version: `13.3.1` and iOS version (real device): `13.3.1`

*Edit*

I can't replace List with `ScrollView` because I have a `ForEach` list of items in my real app, so don't post an answer considering using `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> in a real world app, there might be some business logic happens inside
>   the button's action

seems to be a little bit alogical.You can simply conditionally disable the link (and inform the user, that the link is unavailable by visual appearance)

```
NavigationLink(...).disabled(onCondition)
```

where

```
func disabled(_ disabled: Bool) -> some View
```

Parameters

disabled

A Boolean value that determines whether users can interact with this view.

Return Value

A view that controls whether users can interact with this view.

Discussion

The higher views in a view hierarchy can override the value you set on this view. In the following example, the button isn’t interactive because the outer disabled(_:) modifier overrides the inner one:

```
HStack {
    Button(Text("Press")) {}
    .disabled(false)
}
.disabled(true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clean solution. But Disabling a View would change its appearance as you said, is there a way to customize the disabled color of the view ?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your goal, it can be as follows

```
List {
    Text("Text 1")
    Text("Text 2")
    Text("Text 3")
    LinkView(showDetails: $showDetail)
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $showDetail) { EmptyView() })
}
```

and

```
struct LinkView: View {
    @Binding var showDetails: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showDetails = true // < activate by some logic
        }) {
            Text("Open Details")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use .disable(true) it will reduce your list item opacity like a disabled button, to prevent this. use below code style. Use Navigation Link in backGround and check your navigation condition on Tap Gesture of your view.

```
VStack{
        List(0..<yourListArray.count, id: \.self) { index in  

        {
            Text("\(yourListArr[index].firstName)")
        }().onTapGesture{
            let jobType = getFlags(jobsArr: yourListArray, index:index) 
           if jobType.isCancelledFlag == true{
               self.shouldNavigate = false
           }else{
               self.shouldNavigate = true
           }
        }//Tap Gesture End
        .background(NavigationLink(destination: YourDestinationView(),isActive: self.$shouldNavigate) {
         }.hidden())}}//vStack
```

Comment: Ranges are considered unsafe when using SwiftUI. You should watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: You are right, it is just to clear the concept. In Current update its safe not showing any warnings.